# Return string from rpgle program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I want to return string from rpgle program.

```
/free 
return 'this is simple text';
/end-free
```

Can any please give me code snippet for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A program object must return values via parameters. If you want to return a value with the `RETURN` op code, you need to use a sub-procedure. A sub-procedure can be contained in a program object or a service program object. If you want to share the sub-procedure with multiple programs, you should use a service program. This is how you would define the sub-procedure for use within a service program:

```
dcl-proc MyProcedure Export;
  dcl-pi *n Varchar(25);
  end-pi;

  return 'this is simple text';
end-proc;
```

If you are just defining the sub-procedure within a program, you need to omit the `Export` keyword.

To call the sub-procedure you then use something like this:

```
dcl-s string     Varchar(25);

string = MyProcedure();
```

## To return a value from a Program

If you really want to return a value from a program you have to do it with parameters like this:

```
ctl-opt DftActGrp(*No) ActGrp(*Caller)
        Main(MyProgram);

dcl-proc MyProgram;
  dcl-pi *n;
    string        Varchar(25);
  end-pi;

  string = 'this is a simple string';
  return;
end-proc;
```

To call the program you would use something like this:

```
dcl-s string      Varchar(25);

dcl-pr MyProgram ExtPgm('MYPROGRAM');
  str          Varchar(25);
end-pr;

MyProgram(string);
```